# How to author a typescript module definition so that it exports a module dependency as its member?

Tags: typescript

Please consider the following scenario: I am attempting to author typescript definitions for two commonJS modules, A and B. B has a dependency on A, and, for convenience, B exports A directly as a property `B.A` so that the user does not need to explicitly `require('A')` in their code.

My question is, how can I author the typescript definition of B so as to export A as a property of B? Here is what I have attempted:

A has various members which it exports:

```
export const foo = 'bar';
```

Then, in B I have tried:

```
import * as A from 'A';
export A;
```

and

```
import * as a from 'A'; 
export var A : a;
```

However, neither of these are valid typescript module definitions.

The goal is, in the typescript code which is consuming B, to be able to write:

```
import B = require('B');
console.log(B.A.foo);
```

What is the correct way to author B's module definition so that it exports A as a property of B?

Comment: `export * from "A";`

Comment: Please see my comment below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207605/how-to-author-a-typescript-module-definition-so-that-it-exports-a-module-depende#comment75434268_44208092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.ts

```
export let foo = 1;
```

B.d.ts

```
import * as A from "./A";

export {
    A
}
```

usage

```
import B from "./B";

console.log(B.A.foo);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work, as it would take the contents of A and re-export it on B. With this technique, you could reference `A.foo`, but not `A.B.foo`. I tried re-exporting inside of a namespace ( `export namespace A {  export * from 'A'; }`), but it seems this is explicitly not allowed, as it fails with error "Export declarations are not permitted in a namespace." Is there a way to export the commonjs module A as a member of B?

Comment: If you could please change file name B.ts to B.d.ts, that would be the correct answer. Thank you for your help with this!